# prism combobox selecteditem not fired

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I am using prism with this.
My combobox populates correctly but when I choose an item the selecteditem binding is not called.

Here is the code.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MillLathe"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding MachineType}" DisplayMemberPath="Machine" SelectedItem="Binding Path=SelectedMachine" />
```

In the Viewmodel:

```
        private ObservableCollection<MachineType> _machineType = new ObservableCollection<MachineType>();
    public ObservableCollection<MachineType> MachineType
    {
        get
        {
            return _machineType;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _machineType, value);
        }
    }

    private MachineType _selectedMachine;
    public MachineType SelectedMachine
    {
        get { return _selectedMachine; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedMachine, value); }
    }
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten curly brackets in the view. only this . Put Selected Item's value in the curly brackets:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MillLathe"   
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="115,175,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="120" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MachineType}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Machine" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMachine}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I hate missing stuff like that.